# Laravel 5.1 - Unable to delete file

Tags: php, filesystems, laravel-5.1, delete-file

I have the following code:

```
Storage::delete(public_path($file->path));
```

But I get error:

```
File not found at path: C:\wamp\www\laravel\acme\public\img/logos/1486846424_acme.gif
```

When I check the directory I can see the file is there so why I'm I unable to delete it. I've tried the php `unlink` function too and I get same error.

Comment: It might be related to directory separator, have you tried the file path as \logos\..

Comment: @Khem yes i have but makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works if I use:

```
File::delete(public_path($file->path));
```

Seems like to delete files from the public path you have to use the above - File::delete and to delete files from the storage path you have to use below - Storage::delete:

```
Storage::delete(public_path($file->path));
```

Comment: in your second example, are you sure you're supposed to have a link to the public_path() and not storage_path(), or maybe even nothing but the $file->path?